# Visualforce components disappeared after an action

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, form, table, actionsupport

I am looking into a strange Visualforce effect. Now the problem can be simplified using the following example.

MyController:

```
public class MyController {        
    public String firstName {get; set;}
    
    public PageReference doAction() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Visualforce MyPage:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:form id="myForm">
        <apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:inputText value="{!firstName}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!doAction}" rerender="myForm" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
        
        <table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Benefit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:MyComponent/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

MyComponent:

```
<apex:component>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Test name</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</apex:component>
```

When a value is changed in the `inputText`, the form gets re-rendered but the content in MyComponent disappeared. This seems to be a very old issue. A similar problem can be found here but there is no answer: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000962mIAA

I am refactoring a long Visualforce page that has the same component's `<tr>` content which is large itself. Since the `<tr>` content is duplicated in many places, it should ideally be wrapped in a component. I'm a bit stuck on the issue as otherwise I have to repeat the same `<tr>` content everywhere in the page. Am I missing something fairly straight-forward?

Comment: That's interesting. I have no idea how to fix this aside from just moving to Lightning or otherwise using client-side rendering. I'll see if I can't get someone to look in to this at Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue @sfdcfox.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the "why" your problem happens, but I would try solving it by narrowing the scope of the rerender, e.g. try to rerender a panel around your `<table>` element:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:form id="myForm">
        <apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:inputText value="{!firstName}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!doAction}" rerender="panelToRerender" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
        
        <apex:outputPanel id="panelToRerender" layout="block">
            <table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Benefit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:MyComponent/>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The generic idea is: wrap the block you want to rerender with a panel and rerender it instead. It helped me a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks a lot Francesco. This does fix the problem. It seems that re-rendering the wrapping component (panel or form) caused it.